# Showing data in group by

Tags: sql, group-by, jasper-reports, ireport

I am running a query which get data from multiple tables and condition with inner join. I want this query to group by a single column but when i do it i get: `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`, error message. Well as per my understanding this is because of other table column which not support this group by.

This query I am writing to generate reports from *iReport*. for example below column I am getting from three different tables details, food and hobbies, I want to combine this result group by name...

```
Name  |    food |     hobby 
-------------------------
peter | chips   | traveling 
peter | burger  | tennis 
peter | burger  | writing 
Dave  | lamb    | game 
Dave  | kebab   | reading
```

fine result that i want will be: here I only want to get name once and respective all values (even when it is duplicate) and other duplicate name rows should not contains any data..please help me with this sql query.. if there's any option in *iReport* to do this please let me know or any other keyword/inner queries in sql, i tried there group by option while you design table in it.. but it is not working... thanks in advance

```
Name | food     |  hobby 
-------------------------------------------------------------- 
peter  | chips  | traveling 
------ | burger | tennis 
------ | burger | writing 
Dave   | lamb   | game 
-------| kebab  | reading
```

Query for it:

```sql
SELECT org.Location AS organisation_location, list.listId as list_listid, org.Centre AS org_Centre, 
org.Department AS org_Department, org.Position AS org_Position, q.content AS q_content, 
q.dueTime AS q_dueTime, a.submitted_date AS a_submitted_date, list.frequency AS list_frequency, 
a.comments AS a_comments, a.userid AS a_userid, a.submitted as a_submitted 
FROM org INNER JOIN list ON org.id = list.org_id INNER JOIN q ON klist.id = q.list_id INNER JOIN a ON qid = a.q_id 
WHERE a.submitted=0 andlist.listid='xyz'
```

I want to group the same by *list.listid*

Comment: [Data Grouping](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/index.html#groups)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? This is quite easy using window functions.

Answer (score 1):

Your query doesn't contain "Name", "Food" or "Hobby" so I'm little confused, but following query should help you create your own to achieve desired goal.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN X.VERIFY_COL = 1 THEN X.YOUR_UNIQUE_COL ELSE NULL END AS YOUR_COL_NAME,
* FROM 
    (SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YOUR_UNIQUE_COL ORDER BY YOUR_UNIQUE_COL) AS VERIFY_COL,
        * FROM YOUR_VIEW
    ) X
```

You can partition your data by column you would like to have only once in your query `YOUR_UNIQUE_COL`. Then easy take advantage of `ROW_COUNT()` to set `NULL` for all rows' names with `ROW_COUNT() > 1`. 
Please note it's SQL SERVER solution. What database engine do you use?

Comment: Your code is actually ANSI SQL - not SQL Server specific (and works on nearly all modern DBMS)

Comment: As far as I know MySQL doesn't have `ROW_NUMBER` equivalent.

Comment: Yes, that's why I included "nearly" and "modern" in my comment. 10 years after they have been included in the SQL standard, window functions can be considered mainstream nowadays just like foreign keys, stored procedures or views. Any DBMS not implementing them is 10 years behind. Something I'd not call "modern" - but that's my personal opinion of course.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to group your data, try deactivating "Print repeated values"